# How to find the time travelling between two vertices in a directed graph using R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to solve a pretty straightforward problem about phone calls simulation. I could just introduce all the data and write a very long and messy code, but I'm trying to solve it using graphs and maybe the package "igraph" on R (or something similar), but i'm never used it before.

To make it simple, I want to make a phone call from New York to Moscow and to reach Moscow, the signal can go through 3 cities with different probabilities:

- The call will go through London with a 0.2 probability
- Paris with 0.3 probability
- Berlin with 0.5 probability

The time for the signal to travel between cities follows a normal distribution. For simplicity, say all the times  follow a standard normal distribution. So, for instance, the sign use 0.2 minutes to travel from London to Moscow.

So, I have something like this picture in mind:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoc7X.jpg

The numbers on the edges are the probabilities that the signal will follow that path.

Now, I would have to simulate the travel of the signal lots of times and say what is the average time it takes to go from New York to Moscow.

My question is how can I program this problem since I don't know how to get two weights on an edge, and I don't know how to loop through vertices.

Any advice you can give me would be very helpful.

Comment: You need some formal way of defining how long it takes to travel through each city first. Right now there's no distinction based on which city a signal travels through

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this uses Monte Carlo simulation. The example below is just meant to get you started.

Assume you have three cities, L, P, and B. The call routing is (0.2, 0.3, 0.5) respectively. The time it takes for a call to go through a given city is normally distributed with mean dependant on the city, and standard deviation = 1 (say, millisecond). In this example, I define the mean time as (30 ms, 20 ms, 10 ms) for L, P, B, respectively. This is what is meant in the comment about defining how long it takes to travel through a city.

Then, we perform the simulation using the code below.

```
Monte.Carlo <- function(df) {
  set.seed(1)
  path   <- sample(df$cities, 1000, p=c(0.2,0.3,0.5), replace=T)
  mu     <- df[match(path,df$cities),]$t.mean
  time   <- sapply(mu,function(mu)rnorm(1,mu))
}
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
cities <- c("L","P","B")
t.mean <- c(30,20,10)
df     <- data.frame(cities,t.mean)
hist(Monte.Carlo(df), breaks=50, xlim=c(5,35),main="(L,P,B)=(30,20,10)")
t.mean <- c(25,20,15)
df     <- data.frame(cities,t.mean)
hist(Monte.Carlo(df), breaks=50, xlim=c(5,35), main="(L,P,B)=(25,20,15)")
t.mean <- c(22,20,18)
df     <- data.frame(cities,t.mean)
hist(Monte.Carlo(df), breaks=50, xlim=c(5,35), main="(L,P,B)=(22,20,18)")
```

[image]

The simulation proceeds as follows:

1. Define a `path` vector which indicates which city the call is routed through, for each of 1000 calls. This is a random vector of "L", "P", or "B" with the probabilities given in the problem statement.
2. Map the city "names" to mean time using the definitions in `df`.
3. For each call in `path` calculate the routing time as a single random sample from a normal distribution with the appropriate mean.

We then run the simulation three times using different definitions of the mean routing time. Notice in the first case that most calls take around 10ms. This is because, according to our definitions, routing through B(erlin) takes on average 10ms, and on average 50% of the calls go through Berlin.